# Why must new arrays in Solidity be created with the new type[](array_length) notation?

Tags: arrays, memory

I have the following piece of code in which I try to re-set the funders array to an empty array.

```
contract FundMe {
    address[] public funders; 

    function withdraw() public {
        for (uint i=0; i < funders.length; i++) {
            address funder = funders[i];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder]=0; 
        }
        funders = address[](0);
    }


}
```

I do not undersstand why the final line cannot instead be written as 'funders = address[]'. Also, doesn't 'funders = address' create a static array of length zero that will later have to be re-sized?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what solc version are you using, but the correct way to reset an array in solc v0.8 is

```
funders = new address[](0);
```

The other suggested syntax are not accepted by the compiler.

It is a subjective matter. If you propose a change of syntax and submit patches the solc developers may consider other approaches.